# Launching Adobe Air app from my Android app

Tags: java, android, apache-flex, android-activity, air

It it possible to start an adobe air apk from my current android app?

I tried this code but I got  `ActivityNotFoundException`:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("air.caarsvcmobile.debug");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="caarsvcmobile"
        android:label="CAARS Video Chat" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="air.caarsvcmobile.debug" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Is it possible to check package name and class name of an Air app?

Comment: After some Googling I found the solution of my problem: Since I only knew the package name of the apk file I could use this code to launch the default launcher activity. Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); PackageManager manager = getPackageManager(); i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackag("air.caarsvcmobile.debug"); i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); startActivity(i); Thats all. It works fine.

Comment: excellent that you found a solution, you should post it as an answer to your own question so it's a bit easier to read though and you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some Googling I found the solution of my problem:

Since I only knew the package name of the apk file I could use this code to launch the default launcher activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("air.caarsvcmobile.debug");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

Thats all. I works fine.